# PySpark - Error when checking if I have NaN in some columns

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Try to check if I have NaN value in some columns with

```
ddf_temp = ddf.select('col1', 'col2' ...) # all int type
ddf_temp.select([count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in ddf_temp.columns]).show()
```

I could isolate which columns gives me those error but I cannot find out why I got this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-76c75cf06695> in <module>()
      3 # ddf_temp = ddf10.select('state_bottle_cost')
      4 ddf_temp = ddf10.where(col('state_bottle_retail').isNull())
----> 5 ddf_temp.show()
      6 # ddf_temp = ddf10.select('store_number', 'zip_code', 'county_number', 'category', 'vendor_number', 'pack', 'bottles_sold')
      7 # ddf_temp.select([count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in ddf_temp.columns]).show()

3 frames
/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2010.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 233, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-11-9ec9e286520d>", line 3, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-11-9ec9e286520d>", line 3, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)
```

EDIT :

```
remove_first_char = udf(lambda x: x[1:])
ddf4 = ddf3.withColumn('State Bottle Cost', remove_first_char('State Bottle Cost'))
```

```
multiply_by_100 = udf(lambda x: x*100)

ddf5 = ddf4.withColumn('State Bottle Cost', ddf4['State Bottle Cost'].cast(DoubleType()))
ddf5 = ddf5.withColumn('State Bottle Cost', multiply_by_100('State Bottle Cost'))
ddf5 = ddf5.withColumn('State Bottle Cost', ddf5['State Bottle Cost'].cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: does ddf_temp.show() work? are you applying a udf before or do you read it directly from disk? due to lazy execution the actual error might already be way before this show and might not have anything to do with the count null

Comment: .show() work and yes the columns that gives me trouble have previously been wrangle via an UDF.

Comment: This cannot be an issue because of memory usage ?

Comment: It's because of the UDF. If I do the same on the column pre-UDF I don't have any trouble.

Comment: what is the type of the object returned from udf? if it is pandas or numpy, try to convert it to float() or int()

Comment: Can you provide the code of the udf?

Comment: Done it @Paul. I fix it by using pure pyspark function but I want to undestand why I got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Nones in your dataframe and by applying the UDF it will execute `None[1:]` which gives you the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` (you can try it in a python shell).

When using built-in pyspark functions it will always map null->null. If you would want to do it via UDF (which is not recommended since spark does internal optimization on built-in sql functions), you would need to catch the `None` case: `lambda x: x if not x else x[1:]`

Comment: Thank you for the trick... and yes after read extra documentation I totally understand that if I want efficient code I need to do everything with the builtin function of pyspark.. That's gonna force me to do and learn functional programming then.